# Building hierarchy model C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I've hierarchy model :

```
public class SearchHierarchyModel : 
   {
    public string RowID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SearchHierarchyModel> Children { get; set; }
   }
```

which is suppose to be populated from entities:

```
ground // entity list of grounds
building // entity list of buildings based on grounds ids
floors // entity list of floors based on building ids
```

These my helper objects:

```
 var Building = new SearchHierarchyModel();
 var Ground = new SearchHierarchyModel();
 var TopNode = new SearchHierarchyModel();
var GroundList = new List<SearchHierarchyModel>();
```

And this are the loops which suppose to populate the hierarchy:

```
foreach (var gr in ground)
            {
                var BuildingList = new List<SearchHierarchyModel>();
                foreach (var by in building)
                {
                    BuildingList.Add(new SearchHierarchyModel
                    {
                        Name = by.building,
                        Type = "BUI",
                        RowID = by.Id.ToString()
                    });
                    foreach (var fl in floors)
                    {
                        if (by.Id == fl.Bygning_Bygning_id)
                        {
                            var FloorList = new List<SearchHierarchyModel>();
                            FloorList.Add(new SearchHierarchyModel
                            {
                                Name = fl.floor,
                                Type = "FLR",
                                RowID = fl.Id.ToString()
                            });
                            Building.Children = FloorList;
                        }
                    }
                    Ground.Children = BuildingList;
                }
                TopNode.Children = GroundList;
            }
            return TopNode.Children.ToList();
        }
```

But what is wrong it this hierarchy is that top level (ground) should have two child (two buildings) and it is empty set now and these one of that building should have two child (floor). Any ideas what is wrong with that loops?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding new instances of your objects into the temporary lists and then set these lists to be children of the only instances Building, Ground e.t.c.

There is a huge pointer mess in your loop,

If I'm not misunderstanding, the following is the code you should execute:

```
var TopNode = new SearchHierarchyModel();

var groundList = new List<SearchHierarchyModel>();

foreach (var gr in ground)
{
    SearchHierarchyModel newGround = new SearchHierarchyModel()
    {
        Name = gr.ground,
        Type = "GRD",
        RowID = gr.Id.ToString()
    };

    groundList.Add(newGround);

    var buildingList = new List<SearchHierarchyModel>();

    foreach (var by in building)
    {
        SearchHierarchyModel newBuilding = new SearchHierarchyModel()
        {
            Name = by.building,
            Type = "BUI",
            RowID = by.Id.ToString()
        };

        buildingList.Add(newBuilding);

        foreach (var fl in floors)
        {
            if (by.Id == fl.Bygning_Bygning_id)
            {
                var floorList = new List<SearchHierarchyModel>();
                floorList.Add(new SearchHierarchyModel
                {
                    Name = fl.floor,
                    Type = "FLR",
                    RowID = fl.Id.ToString()
                });
                newBuilding.Children = floorList;
            }
        }
        newGround.Children = buildingList;
    }
    TopNode.Children = groundList;
}
```